# A question about fasting

Tags: sawm

After iftar I applied Vaseline and the next day morning for fast while fasting I think my lips taste like Vaseline and sticky does it break my fast because I like my lips this break my fast and swallow it

Answer (score 0):

‏سلام عليكم

your fast is only broken if you are intentionally eating Vaseline from your lips just don’t eat the Vaseline. when you apply it to your lips don’t lick your lips.

‏الله اعلم